# check if stored procedure passed or failed

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are currently changing all of the SQL server management studio jobs into a more generic job execution service. The problem is the framework does not provide 'steps' like SQL server does. Is there a way to check programmatically if a stored procedure(that i cannot look at) passed or failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC @return_value = your_stored_proc (@param1 = 'somevalue')

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Then, [reference the return value](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190778(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Usually a return code of 0 means that there were zero errors.